# Update entity in mvc4

Tags: linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

i want to update existing row in database, the problem is that i have 4 properties that user is not supposed to update. If i try code bellow it throws error "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key." thx

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id, Name, Author, Price")]Book book)
    {

            book.NewBookId = db.Book.Single(x => x.Id == book.Id).NewBookId;
            book.UsedBookId = db.Book.Single(x => x.Id == book.Id).UsedBookId;
            book.TextBook = db.Book.Single(x => x.Id == book.Id).TextBook;
            book.WorkBook = db.Book.Single(x => x.Id == book.Id).WorkBook;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Book.Attach(book);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(book);

    }
```

View

```
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Author)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Author)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Author)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Book` with the same key already exists.

You are trying to update the existing book, right?

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id, Name, Author, Price")]Book model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var book = db.Book.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.Id);
        if(book != null)
        {
            book.Name = model.Name;
            book.Author = model.Author;
            book.Price= model.Price;

            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("Id", "Couldn't find book id.")
    }

    return View(model);
}
```